# keras: returning model.summary() vs scikit learn wrapper

Tags: python, scikit-learn, keras, wrapper, summary

While working with keras, I learned that using a wrapper comes with adverse effects for keras and scikit learn api requests. I am interested in a solution to have both.

**Variant 1: scikit Wrapper**

```
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier

    def model():
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(10, input_dim=4, activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
        model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
        return model

estimator = KerasClassifier(build_fn=model, epochs=100, batch_size=5)
model.fit(X, y)
```

**->** This lets me print scikit commands such as accuracy_score() or classification_report(). However, model.summary() does not work:

> AttributeError: 'KerasClassifier' object has no attribute 'summary'

**Variant 2: No Wrapper**

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10, input_dim=4, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, y, epochs=100, batch_size=5)
```

**->** This lets me print model.summary() but not the scikit commands.

> ValueError: Mix type of y not allowed, got types {'multiclass',
>   'multilabel-indicator'}

Is there a way that enables to use both?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`KerasClassifier` is just a wrapper over the actual `Model` in `keras` so that the actual methods of the keras api can be routed to the methods used in scikit, so it can be used in conjunction with scikit utilities. But internally it just uses the model which can be accessed by using `estimator.model`.

Example illustrating the above:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
def model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(10, input_dim=20, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

estimator = KerasClassifier(build_fn=model, epochs=100, batch_size=5)
X, y = make_classification()
estimator.fit(X, y)

# This is what you need
estimator.model.summary()
```

The output for this is:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_9 (Dense)              (None, 10)                210       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_10 (Dense)             (None, 2)                 22        
=================================================================
Total params: 232
Trainable params: 232
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Answer (score 1):

The function of the summary is in this library: `from keras. models import Model`
You can see this:[image: for example] [image: Figure]

Answer (score 1):

The same as @Vivek Kumar's answer, just updated to use `scikeras` instead of `keras.wrappers.scikit_learn` which is defunct.

I've left the defunct bits in, just commented out, and with the replacement `scikeras` line directly below, there are a few differences.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
# from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from scikeras.wrappers import KerasClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
def model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(10, input_dim=20, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

# estimator = KerasClassifier(build_fn=model, epochs=100, batch_size=5)
estimator = KerasClassifier(model=model, epochs=100, batch_size=5, verbose=0)
X, y = make_classification()
estimator.fit(X, y)

# This is what you need
# estimator.model.summary()
estimator.model_.summary()
```